# Conda can't find environment

Tags: ubuntu, anaconda, conda, otree

I cloned an Otree project from a colleague via GitHub and want to set up the survey.
When i follow her instructions by typing `conda activate otree_env` i get the error:
*Could not find conda environment: otree_env*.

When i type the complete path, like `conda activate /home/path/to/environment/otree_env`, i get the error: *Not a conda environment: home/path/to/environment/otree_env*.

It seems conda does not discover the environment as `conda info --envs` doesn't list the otree environment.

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unexpectedly I had a similar problem in *Windows* in *Visual Studio Code* terminal when I run `activate C:\...\myEnvironmentFolder` with the message `Could not find conda environment: C:...` The following command helped me:

```
source C:/myPath/Anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
```

Then running `activate C:\...\myEnvironmentFolder` gave the desired effect

If you have the problem like this in *cmd console*, then, probably, you need to set the path in

```
Control panel -> System -> Advanced system settings -> User / System variables -> Path -> Edit -> New ->
and add
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin
```